# Getting and storing access tokens using base_facebook.php and facebook.php?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, access-token, facebook-oauth

Using the above libraries, I can get the details of a user, his authorisation, his friends, but only once: I need to store the access_token and key in database, so the user can access his friends walls or other public details.
Can anyone help?
(I have used OAuth for Twitter and Tumblr, but I can't get it for FB).

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Be careful with saving the token. When not requesting all-time permission, it expires in a certain time (what might be your problem)

When using a canvas app (the ones integrated in apps.facebook.com) requesting another token is quite simple. Facebook posts a signed_request parameter to your app whenever a user accesses it (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

Decode it, pass it to the Graph API, profit.

Comment: ok... This leads to two questions: how to get a permanent token and how to get another token and decode it?  I show a list of friends, and, on the side, I want to show the last entry on the friend's wall. (see http://ethan.jrcw3.com, user "bravo", pwd "pwdpwd" and check "my network".  Click Twitter logo and see extracts.  Want to do the same with FB, clicking FB logo)  Lost in the documentation...

Comment: if you need all time access, you have to ask for the "offline_acess" permission in the oauth dialog using the "scope" parameter https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

if you need a generic access_token without a login... you can use    $appID ."|". $secKey
this is called a APP access token, so it would be logged in as the "Application" not a user

!!! make sure you use this on https://graph.facebook.com/ !!!

hints the "https://" for secure SSL connection
but the API already determines this.